# Why is the polynomial regression returning the same results for different grades?

Tags: python, pandas, machine-learning, scikit-learn, regression

I have this dataframe and I want to calculate the polynomial regression for ozone. I pass o3 as y value, and the dates as x value. Why does my polynomial regression look the same for grade 2 to 15? I have compared grade 4 to grade 15 and there is no difference... I have compared the obtained regressions to CurveExpert software, and they are entirely different... How to solve the problems and to view differences between grade 4 and 15?

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import datetime as dt
import pandas as pd

# Importing the dataset
dataset = pd.read_csv('https://raw.githubusercontent.com/iulianastroia/csv_data/master/final_dataframe.csv')


dataset['day'] = pd.to_datetime(dataset['day'], dayfirst=True)
dataset = dataset.sort_values(by=['readable time'])
print(dataset.head())

group_by_df = pd.DataFrame([name, group.mean()["o3"]] for name, group in dataset.groupby('day'))
group_by_df.columns = ['day', "o3"]
group_by_df['day'] = pd.to_datetime(group_by_df['day'])
group_by_df['day'] = group_by_df['day'].map(dt.datetime.toordinal)
X = group_by_df[['day']].values
y = group_by_df[['o3']].values

# Splitting the dataset into the Training set and Test set
from sklearn.model_selection import train_test_split
X_train, X_test, y_train, y_test = train_test_split(X, y, test_size=0.2, random_state=0)


# Fitting Linear Regression to the dataset
from sklearn.linear_model import LinearRegression
lin_reg = LinearRegression()
lin_reg.fit(X, y)

# Visualizing the Linear Regression results
def viz_linear():
    plt.scatter(X, y, color='red')
    plt.plot(X, lin_reg.predict(X), color='blue')
    plt.title('Linear Regression')
    plt.xlabel('Date')
    plt.ylabel('O3 levels')
    plt.show()
    return
viz_linear()

# Fitting Polynomial Regression to the dataset
from sklearn.preprocessing import PolynomialFeatures
poly_reg = PolynomialFeatures(degree=15)
X_poly = poly_reg.fit_transform(X)
pol_reg = LinearRegression()
pol_reg.fit(X_poly, y)

# Visualizing the Polymonial Regression results
def viz_polymonial():
    plt.scatter(X, y, color='red')
    plt.plot(X, pol_reg.predict(poly_reg.fit_transform(X)), color='blue')
    plt.title('poly Regression grade 15')
    plt.xlabel('Date')
    plt.ylabel('O3 levels')
    plt.show()
    return
viz_polymonial()
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you are so close. Nice job, you have a lot going on here.

I think you want to fit the test sets like this for linear:

```
# Fitting Linear Regression to the dataset
from sklearn.linear_model import LinearRegression
lin_reg = LinearRegression()
lin_reg.fit(X_test, y_test)
```

and like this for Polynomial:

```
# Fitting Polynomial Regression to the dataset
from sklearn.preprocessing import PolynomialFeatures
poly_reg = PolynomialFeatures(degree=15)
X_poly = poly_reg.fit_transform(X_test)
pol_reg = LinearRegression()
pol_reg.fit(X_poly, y_test)
```

now the curves show visually much different

[image]

Comment: is it wrong if i use numbers from 1 to the len of dataframe+1 for the x axis? I think the posix codes give me wrong results in the regression: ```dataset['numbered'] = ''
for i in range(1, len(dataset) + 1):
    dataset.loc[i - 1, ['numbered']] = i

X = dataset[['numbered']].values ```

Comment: I think I recall (n+1, 1) was the way to go for this method but I'll check and confirm and get back to you ... JP

Comment: Thank you, @Jeanpierre Fisher, looking forward to your response :)

Comment: Take a look here:
https://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.preprocessing.PolynomialFeatures.html
I think this will get you on the right track, It says:

Generate polynomial and interaction features.

Generate a new feature matrix consisting of all polynomial combinations of the features with degree less than or equal to the specified degree. 

For example, if an input sample is two dimensional and of the form [a, b],

the degree-2 polynomial features are [1, a, b, a^2, ab, b^2].